# TargetInvocationException when running project on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, windows-phone-8

I have a large wp7 project, which worked fine on wp7. During several last weeks, i used wp8 device for debugging (project is still for wp7) and it was fine.

Now, i started testing it on wp7 device, and it throws me at the line

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/MyApp;component/App.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

this exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  Message=TargetInvocationException
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass30.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2a()
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)
       at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.CreateInstance(XamlTypeToken inXamlType, XamlQualifiedObject& newObject)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponentNative(IntPtr pContext, IntPtr pComponent, UInt32 cUriStringLength, String uriString, UInt32 cXamlStrLength, Byte* pXamlStr, UInt32 cAssemblyStrLength, String assemblyStr)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponent(IManagedPeerBase componentAsDO, String resourceLocator, UnmanagedMemoryStream stream, UInt32 numBytesToRead, String assemblyString)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at MyApp.App.InitializeComponent()
       at MyApp.App..ctor()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass30.<GetCreateObjectDelegate>b__2a()
       at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)
       at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.CreateKnownObject(IntPtr nativeRootPeer, UInt32 customTypeId, String initializationString, IntPtr& nativePeer, UInt32 isCreatedByParser)
       at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.CreateUnknownObject(String assemblyName, String typeName, IntPtr nativeRootPeer, String initializationString, UInt32& customTypeId, UInt32& coreTypeId, UInt32& typeFlags, IntPtr& nativePeer)
  InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
       Message=Could not load type 'System.Func`2' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'.
```

I changed tons of things, so i have no idea where to look.

Any suggestions of what can be a reason? And what is `System.Func'2`?

EDIT: Just to clarify it once again: project was always targeted wp7. And it currently is: [image]

EDIT2: Output is:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Device.dll' 
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Background.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
```

Maybe it can help? Is there something wrong with Serialization.dll on wp7?

EDIT3: My system config: Windows 8.1 Pro, MSVS Pro 2012 Update 4.

Comment: You can't run an application targeted for WP8 on WP7. You either have to have two separate projects targeting WP7 and WP8, or keep the project targeting WP7, so both OS's can run the application.

Comment: It is wp7 application. Just edited question to clarify that.

Comment: So you targeted it to WP8 and changed it back to WP7?

Comment: @CamBruce Nope, i just used WP8 device for testing. It is/was always wp7 project.

Comment: if you are just deploying over the wp7 app, try completely uninstalling the app, run a 'clean solution' in VS, and re-deploy.

Comment: @CamBruce Just tried again exactly as you said - still the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've managed to solve the issue. The problem is with Newtonsoft.Json library, current version (6.0.3) is claimed to be compatible with wp7, but on practice it is not.

[image]

Solution: just roll back to 5.0.8: 
`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 5.0.8`

Comment: So, this was internal to your project with nothing related to using wp8 wp7 devices and any project target changes. Well, great :)

Comment: @GauravDeochakke yep :) however, i got another one issue: server calls are working fine on wp8 and throws NotFound exceptions on wp7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816912/network-errors-on-wp7

Answer (score 0):

Once you open your WP7 app in VS 2012 with WP SDK 8.0 with target platform for WP8 you can't use this project anymore as WP7 project. If you want to continue to develop in new environment in VS 2012 you need to use Target platform: WP 7.1. 
Do check what the target platform is set to.

If you want to support WP 7 OS, you need to maintain two different applications and submit them independently to the store.
So, it seems that you opened the project with vs2012 and sdk 8.0 and then built and ran it on wp8 and then trying again to do so for a wp7 device.
Thats what , i think should be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the project **is** wp7 oriented. I updated the question. Usually, i submited a wp7 project and it works on both wp7 and wp8.

Comment: Would you please clarify "During last time, i developed it using only wp8 device for debugging (project is still for wp7)." this statement of yours?
That is making me think in a wrong direction.

Comment: Yesh, sorry - looking like i formulated it in a quite weird manner. I meaned that i used wp8 device for testing wp7 project and it was fine. Now i'm using wp7 device for testing the same wp7 project, but it throws me an exception.

Comment: What version of visual studio and windows do you use?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro, using MSVS Pro 2012, Update 4.